# При использовании LogManager в веб приложении возникает ошибка

Tags: java, логирование, glassfish

Есть сервлет. Но возникает ошибка при считывании файла свойств. В обычном JavaApp все работает. В чем может быть проблема?

```
@Override
public void init (ServletConfig config) throws ServletException {
    super.init(config);

    try {
        // тут ошибка                                       
        LogManager.getLogManager().readConfiguration(
                MyServlet.class.getResourceAsStream("D:\\...\\logging.properties"));

    } catch (IOException ex) {
            Logger.getLogger(MyServlet.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
    }
        System.err.println("Could not setup logger configuration: " + e.toString());
    }
    log = Logger.getLogger(MyServlet.class.getName());
}
```

Файл свойств:

```
handlers= java.util.logging.FileHandler
java.util.logging.FileHandler.level =ALL
java.util.logging.FileHandler.pattern = D:/.../log.txt
java.util.logging.FileHandler.limit = 1000000
java.util.logging.FileHandler.formatter = java.util.logging.SimpleFormatter
```

---

Так и не разобрался, поставил log4j

Comment: getResourceAsStream обращается к загрузчику класса, а загрузчики классов имеют своё представление о том, что им доступно. Возможно загрузчик классов-сервлетов ограничен веб-приложением, для остального руки коротки.

Comment: а какая ошибка возникает то?  трейс в студию